# How do I stop all imported models coming in with blend mode set to 'alpha blend'?

Tags: import, transparency, .fbx, obj

Every OBJ or FBX I import seems to be set to 'alpha blend' inside of Blender by default.

I have a lot of objects in an FBX file that I want to bring in, but they all come in as 'alpha blend'. I don't want a way to change the blend mode after the fact, but to stop it coming in like that at all.

I'm on Blender 2.93.4, but it's been happening for a while.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't. it's either change it after the fact (you can do a bunch at once), or modify the importer. Cf https://developer.blender.org/T89630.